# Given an affine variety and any two points, we can find a regular function which takes one point to another.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think this result is true. Obviously in case of projective varieties this is not true. Is this a sufficient result to show that something is not an affine variety ?

I am not able to prove it ?

Any hints ..

**Edit**

I want a morphism(regular map) $X\rightarrow X$
which sends x to y.

Comment: Do you mean a morphism $X\rightarrow X$ which sends $x\mapsto y$, or a function $f$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$ ? This is not clear from your question and the fact you said that this is obviously false for projective variety.

Comment: @Roland  I mean a morphism(regular map) $X\rightarrow X$ which sends $x$ to $y$.

Comment: @Roland I think my statement that "this is obviously false for projective variety' is wrong

Comment: Aren't constant maps regular?

Comment: Sure constant maps are regular

Comment: Over a non algebraically closed field and using scheme, you need to be careful. You can't send a point with a small residue field to a point with a bigger residue field. Now, with this precision, you can see that it works for any $X$ (I mean, we never use the fact that $X$ was affine).

Comment: @Roland Thanks I got it. So this is true in general for any quasi projective variety.